# Ftp bunch of files from multiple directories into one directory

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, sh

I have a command to print all the cpp files

find / -name *.cpp

I would like to ftp the result of all of these into my ftp directory /backup

How would I go about merging ftp command along with  find command to ftp all the cpp files into one ftp directory. Sorry I am quite new to ftp command handling and know only the basics, and would like to find an answer, or if someone could link to a good tutorial that would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-exec` option to find to take action on every file matched. The `curl` command can be used to upload the files:

```
find / -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec curl -T {} ftp://somesite/somedir/ --user myname:mypassword \;
```